# how to add new proprties to new members in umbraco 5

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco5

I want to add new properties to be added in registering new members in umbraco 5 like address and phone and displaying it in his profile.

Thanks.

Comment: I would advise looking on http://our.umbraco.org for help. There is a wiki and forum there with some fantastic individuals always willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

As of mid-June the Umbraco 5 project has been cancelled.  Many of the best features will be migrated to Umbraco 4 and that will be the main branch moving forward.

Read more here:

http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/v5-rip.aspx/

There is already a package that helps bring the MVC goodness to Umbraco 4

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/umbramvco